# DNS configuration doesn't work

Tags: linux

I had configured a DNS server.But when nslookup with the IP address of the DNS server.
It shows something like that"x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa   name=dns.domain.com".
But when i nslookup with the dns.domain.com output is ok.

Answer (score 4):

The output of nslookup is to be expected.

When you look up an IP address for which a PTR record is set up, the result is that same IP address, with the octets printed in reverse order, ending with `in-addr.arpa`.

Finally, you get the corresponding fully qualified domain name set in the PTR record.

If a PTR record is not set, you will get NXDOMAIN as a lookup result for that IP address.

**Example of a result of a reverse lookup with a PTR record**

I do a lookup of twitter.com

```
kenny@computer ~ $ nslookup twitter.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   twitter.com
Address: 199.59.148.10
Name:   twitter.com
Address: 199.59.148.82
Name:   twitter.com
Address: 199.59.150.39
```

I now do a reverse lookup of the first result of my previous lookup.

```
kenny@computer ~ $ nslookup 199.59.148.10
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
10.148.59.199.in-addr.arpa  name = r-199-59-148-10.twttr.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

Ok, so it turns out that the folks at twitter set up a PTR record for that IP address (note that the octets of the IP in the output are reversed, beginning with 10 and ending with 199) that points to r-199-59-148-10.twttr.com.

**Example of a result of a reverse lookup without a PTR record**
Let's do the same thing for this website, stackoverflow.com

```
kenny@computer ~ $ nslookup stackoverflow.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   stackoverflow.com
Address: 69.59.197.21
```

The result is only one IP address, let's do a reverse lookup on that.

```
kenny@computer ~ $ nslookup 69.59.197.21
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

** server can't find 21.197.59.69.in-addr.arpa.: NXDOMAIN
```

Again, the octets in the output have been reversed and appended with `.in-addr.arpa`. The result this time is not a domain name, but NXDOMAIN. No PTR record is set.

Comment: Dumb question, but what's a PTR record? Can you link to details about it?